# Mounting USB on HELiOS Linux

Tags: linux, usb

I want to mount the USB drive on the Linux OS(HELiOS) via command line, there is a ISO image present in the USB. I want to see the directories present in the ISO image. Label/Name given to the USB is "LIVE".

Can somebody help with commands to mount and see the contents of the ISO image file.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the file system of your disk?

Answer (score 0):

Following command will mount USB device at /dev/sda1 on /mnt which has fat32 file system.

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```

If you dont know the device name of the disk run this command just after attaching it to USB port.

```
dmesg  | tail | egrep '[hs]d[a-z]: [hs]d[a-z][0-9]+'
```

This will show you the device name. Like it shows `[589.289070]  sdc: sdc1` in my pc. Then device name would be `/dev/sdc1`. `/mnt` directory is already there all the time.

Following command will mount the iso.

```
mkdir ~/iso
mount /mnt/isofile.iso ~/iso -o loop
```

See the contents in the iso.

```
ls ~/iso
```